# PHPSpec: function returning by reference

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, phpspec

I updated Doctrine 2.5 to 2.6 in my project and phpspec is broken.

The function `getEntityChangeSet()` is now returned by reference. It seems not to be supported by phpspec.

```
$unitOfWork
    ->getEntityChangeSet($site)
    ->willReturn(['_dataParent' => [0 => 2, 1 => 3]]);
```

The response is
`returning by reference not supported`

the underlying function ([doctrine/doctrine2](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L476)) is

```
public function & getEntityChangeSet($entity)
{
    $oid  = spl_object_hash($entity);
    $data = [];

    if (!isset($this->entityChangeSets[$oid])) {
        return $data;
    }

    return $this->entityChangeSets[$oid];
}
```

Do you know if it's possible to bypass this or change test for make it work?

Comment: Why by reference?

Comment: @SenseException: The function mentionned is vendor code: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L476

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer has been given on Twitter by [@Pamilme](https://twitter.com/pamilme/status/986206734262861824)

You have to mock UnitOfWork with Mockery. An example can be found [here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/41063712cd15eb19418d993c46d782dade724b96/src/Sylius/Bundle/ProductBundle/spec/EventListener/SelectProductAttributeChoiceRemoveListenerSpec.php#L48-L62):

```
    /** @var UnitOfWork|MockInterface $unitOfWork */
    $unitOfWork = Mockery::mock(UnitOfWork::class);
    $unitOfWork->shouldReceive('getEntityChangeSet')->withArgs([$productAttribute->getWrappedObject()])->andReturn([
        'configuration' => [
            ['choices' => [
                '8ec40814-adef-4194-af91-5559b5f19236' => 'Banana',
                '1739bc61-9e42-4c80-8b9a-f97f0579cccb' => 'Pineapple',
            ]],
            ['choices' => [
                '8ec40814-adef-4194-af91-5559b5f19236' => 'Banana',
            ]],
        ],
    ]);
    $entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->willReturn($unitOfWork);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you extends TestCase on your test class, you can also do something like:

```
$uow = $this->createMock(UnitOfWork::class);
$uow->method('getEntityChangeSet')->willReturn(['_dataParent' => [0 => 2, 1 => 3]);
```